# Semaphore crashes android app

Tags: java, android, button, semaphore

As a first-timer trying to make a quick-and-easy android app for Comp Sci at high school, I've been working to port a functioning adventure-style game to android 5.1.1. You choose between two buttons, make your way through a old creepy house, and your choice affects the outcome. The way I went about it was to use a do loop with a switch statement, using semaphores to wait for a choice. Using semaphores seems to crash my app: Logcat shows no errors, but when I placed a debug choice in the beginning before even using the switch function the app crashed when trying to acquire a semaphore. Commenting out the semaphore fixed the problem.

tl;dr What would be a more appropriate way of handling the two-button choice on android?

Here's the code:

Main parts of the adventure game

```
public static Button btnYes, btnNo;
public static TextView textField;
public static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
public static String btnUsed = "";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_adventure);
    btnYes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
    btnNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
    textField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFieldText);
    textField.setText("Debug Screen! Begin?");
    btnYes.setText("Yes");
    btnNo.setText("No");
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
        Switch();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
}

     public void btnYesClicked(View v) {
    btnUsed = Prompts.yes;
    semaphore.release();
}

    public void btnNoClicked(View v) {
        btnUsed = Prompts.no;
        semaphore.release();
    }
    public static void Switch() throws InterruptedException {
    boolean isRunning = true;
    String place = Prompts.doorway;
    String choice = "";
    do {
        switch (place) {
        case Prompts.doorway:
            semaphore.drainPermits();
            textField.setText(Prompts.doorwayPrompt);
            btnYes.setText(Prompts.kitchen);
            btnNo.setText(Prompts.upstairs);
            semaphore.acquire();
            choice = btnUsed;
            if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes) || choice.equals(Prompts.no)) {
                if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes)) {
                    place = Prompts.kitchen;
                } else {
                    place = Prompts.upstairs;
                }
            } else {
                place = "default";
            }
            break;
        case Prompts.kitchen:
            semaphore.drainPermits();
            textField.setText(Prompts.kitchenPrompt);
            btnYes.setText(Prompts.fridge);
            btnNo.setText(Prompts.cabinet);
            semaphore.acquire();
            choice = btnUsed;
            if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes) || choice.equals(Prompts.no)) {
                if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes)) {
                    place = Prompts.fridge;
                } else {
                    place = Prompts.cabinet;
                }
            } else {
                place = "default";
            }
            break;
        case Prompts.upstairs:
            semaphore.drainPermits();
            textField.setText(Prompts.upstairsPrompt);
            btnYes.setText(Prompts.bedroom);
            btnNo.setText(Prompts.bathroom);
            semaphore.acquire();
            choice = btnUsed;
            if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes) || choice.equals(Prompts.no)) {
                if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes)) {
                    place = Prompts.bedroom;
                } else {
                    place = Prompts.bathroom;
                }
            } else {
                place = "default";
            }
            break;
        case Prompts.fridge:
            semaphore.drainPermits();
            textField.setText(Prompts.fridgePrompt);
            btnYes.setText(Prompts.yes);
            btnNo.setText(Prompts.no);
            semaphore.acquire();
            choice = btnUsed;
            if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes) || choice.equals(Prompts.no)) {
                if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes)) {
                    textField.setText(Prompts.fridgeYes);
                    place = "done";
                } else {
                    textField.setText(Prompts.fridgeNo);
                    place = "done";
                }
            }
            break;
        case Prompts.cabinet:
            semaphore.drainPermits();
            textField.setText(Prompts.cabinetPrompt);
            btnYes.setText(Prompts.yes);
            btnNo.setText(Prompts.no);
            semaphore.acquire();
            choice = btnUsed;
            if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes) || choice.equals(Prompts.no)) {
                if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes)) {
                    textField.setText(Prompts.cabinetYes);
                    place = "done";
                } else {
                    textField.setText(Prompts.cabinetNo);
                    place = "done";
                }
            }
            break;
        case Prompts.bedroom:
            semaphore.drainPermits();
            textField.setText(Prompts.bedroomPrompt);
            btnYes.setText(Prompts.yes);
            btnNo.setText(Prompts.no);
            semaphore.acquire();
            choice = btnUsed;
            if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes) || choice.equals(Prompts.no)) {
                if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes)) {
                    textField.setText(Prompts.bedroomYes);
                    place = "done";
                } else {
                    textField.setText(Prompts.bedroomNo);
                    place = "done";
                }
            }
            break;
        case Prompts.bathroom:
            semaphore.drainPermits();
            textField.setText(Prompts.bathroomPrompt);
            btnYes.setText(Prompts.yes);
            btnNo.setText(Prompts.no);
            semaphore.acquire();
            choice = btnUsed;
            if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes) || choice.equals(Prompts.no)) {
                if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes)) {
                    textField.setText(Prompts.bathroomYes);
                    place = "done";
                } else {
                    textField.setText(Prompts.bathroomNo);
                    place = "done";
                }
            }
            break;
        case "done":
            semaphore.drainPermits();
            btnYes.setText("Again");
            btnNo.setText("Finish");
            semaphore.acquire();
            choice = btnUsed;
            if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes) || choice.equals(Prompts.no)) {
                if (choice.equals(Prompts.yes)) {
                    place = Prompts.doorway;
                } else {
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
        default:
            textField.setText("Not a valid answer!");
            break;
        }
    } while (isRunning);
}
```

Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Adventure">

<TextView android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textFieldText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/yes"
    android:id="@+id/buttonYes"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonNo"
    android:onClick="btnYesClicked"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no"
    android:id="@+id/buttonNo"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="btnNoClicked"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: a/ always log stuff in your catch blocks, otherwise how are you going to know what happened? b/ you can't go blocking the ui thread like that. All the ui stuff happens on the ui thread, namely, both `btnYesClicked` and `onCreate`. You can see how this is a problem.

Comment: Didn't include the catch block stuff because they never came up in the logs. (Mostly because the app stopped responding). The second half of your comment is the point of the question (read the tl;dr), as I assume there is a much better way of doing it.

Comment: basically, you don't need the semaphore. Simply call your state machine function (`Switch`) in your `btnYesClicked` and `btnNoClicked` methods, and remove the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are blocking the UI. A better way to handle it would be to store the `String place` in a field variable (like your button used). Change your `Switch()` method to accept the choice parameter `Switch(String choice)` and eliminate the do/while and then change your `btnYesClicked` and `btnNoClicked` to call the Switch method and pass the correct button.

Comment: Works perfectly. Nice explanation, it worked out well.